# What does *this = NULL mean inside a method in a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, null, this

Inside a templated class, I found the expression, `*this = NULL` What does such an expression mean ?

The following is its definition:

```
TYPE** getPtr() 
{
 *this = NULL;
 return &m_pPtr;
}
```

where m_pPtr is type `TYPE*` in the template class.

Assignment operator:

```
// Assignment operator.
TYPE* operator =(TYPE *pPtr) {
  if (pPtr == m_pPtr)
    return pPtr;

  m_pPtr = pPtr;

  return m_pPtr;
}
```

Vishnu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say what the point of such a statement is without seeing the actual code.

But it will probably be invoking an overloaded assignment operator.  e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
public:
    void operator=(void *) {
        std::cout << "Here!\n";
    }

    void foo() {
        *this = NULL;
    }
};


int main() {
    X x;
    x.foo();
}
```

Comment: @VishnuPedireddi: that's not enough code to figure out what the reason is.  In particular, we would need to see the definition of the assignment operators (`operator=`) and constructors, and also some idea of what this class actually is.

Comment: @VishnuPedireddi: Well, `*this = NULL` is indeed calling that assignment operator, which in turn is setting `m_pPtr` to be `NULL`.  I can't tell you why that is, because you haven't said what this class is!  (i.e. what the purpose of the class is)

Answer (score 0):

It's attempting to assign 0 to the current object. It will call something like

```
operator=(void *);
```

Another possibility (as far as I know) is that there is a constructor in the object which takes a `void*` or similar type. Then it would construct an object and then copy-assign that.

```
T :: T(void *);    // construct with the void *
T :: T(const T &); // copy assignment
```